# How to compare multiple input checkbox values with forloop?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

Here the `data['arrays']` is json response from backend. It will return array with id values of the already checked from list. But I got stuck how can i compare the array[id] with  checkbox input value which is id. if both id are equal enable checked attribute.

script

```
     $('.mybtn').click(function() {
            url=$(this).attr('url');
            $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: 'GET',
            success: function (data) {
              $('#myform').find('input[name="name"]').val(data['title']); #works
              for (let i = 0; i < data['arrays'].length; ++i) {
                 console.log(data['arrays'][i]['id'])   
                   if($('#myform').find('input[name="u"]').val() == data['arrays'][i]['id']){
                  # doesnot works checks all
                 }
                   $('#myform').find('input[name="u"]').attr('checked', true); #checks all
                  }
            },
          });
          });
```

html

dynamic li list

```
 <ul id="myid">
    {% for u in usrs %}
       <li>
        <input type="checkbox" name="u" value={{u.id}}/>
      </li>
    {% endfor %}
```

EDIT:
output of data:

```
Object { title: "Hello World", usrs: (2) […] }
​
title: "Hello World"
​
usrs: Array [ {…}, {…} ]
​​
0: Object { id: 6, name: "hello" }
​​
1: Object { id: 8, name: "nameq" }
​​
length: 2
```

Comment: Hi, can you show output of `data` ?

Comment: @Swati updated in the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `` $(`input[name=u][value=${id}]`).prop('checked', true); `` to set checked checkbox on required inputs.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
//suppose array look like this ...
var data = {
  "arrays": [{
    "id": 1
  }, {
    "id": 3
  }]
}
for (let i = 0; i < data['arrays'].length; ++i) {
  var id = data['arrays'][i]['id'];
  console.log(id)
  //get input with value of id
  $(`input[name=u][value=${id}]`).prop('checked', true);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="myid">

  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" name="u" value=1 />
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" name="u" value=2 />
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" name="u" value=3 />
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: thanks it worked +1 . but however it still  needs to refresh the page when click on another button since the already checked data also appears on another button when doing without page refresh

Comment: *still needs to refresh the page when click on another button...*  Please elaborate more . Also , you can remove checked from all checkboxes before making checked i.e :  `$("input[name=u]").prop("checked",false)` put this line before for-loop.

Comment: `$("input[name=u]").prop("checked",false)` this solved the issue. Thanks